# Should I be getting this error : variable-sized object may not be initialized?

Tags: c, arrays, hash, stack

I'm making a hash table with an array of 9,997 buckets.  I am just currently trying to initialize the entire hash table array with the collisionCount to 0 and the pointers inside the bucket to create the linked list to NULL.  The supplied "data.txt" file provides the bucket count on the first line in the text file, so that is where I am getting the bucket count from.

Anyhow, here is some code :

Hashing .h :

```
#ifndef _Hashing_h
#define _Hashing_h

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct bucket *bucketP;
typedef struct key *keyP;

/*
 * Creates the initial empty bucket array
 * from parameters 
 */
bucketP createBucketArray(FILE *);

#endif
```

Hashing.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "Hashing.h"

struct bucket
{
    int collisionCount;
    keyP *firstKey;
};

struct key
{
    int thisKey;
    keyP *nextKey;
};

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    int bucketCount, keyCount;
    fptr = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    fscanf(fptr, "%d %d", &bucketCount, &keyCount);
    bucketP thisArray = createBucketArray(fptr);
    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}

bucketP createBucketArray(FILE *fp)
{
    int thisBucketCount;
    int i = 0;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &thisBucketCount);
    bucketP thisBucketArray[thisBucketCount] = (bucketP) malloc(sizeof(struct bucket));
    for (i = 0 ; i < thisBucketCount ; i++)
    {
        thisBucketArray[i]->collisionCount = 0;
        thisBucketArray[i]->firstKey = 0x00;
    }
    return thisBucketArray;
}
```

The error reads as follows :

```
error : variable-sized object may not be initialized
...thisBucketArray[thisBucketCount] = (bucketP) malloc(sizeof(struct bucket));
   ^
```

Since this was the first time I got the error message, I researched it and found that the above error message is usually thrown when you try and declare something too large for the stack.  However, the value of 'thisBucketCount' is only 9,997.  That creates an array of 9,997 pretty simple structs (only two parameters in `struct bucket`, one being an int and another being a pointer.

Am I really creating an array that is too large for my stack?  I feel like I would have to make a WAY BIGGER array for that.

Thanks in advance for any advice, thanks thanks thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The error is expected: VLAs (variable length arrays) can't be initialized.

But real problem seems to be that you want `thisBucketCount` number of buckets which is not what this code does:

```
bucketP thisBucketArray[thisBucketCount]=(bucketP)malloc(sizeof(struct bucket));
```

You probably want to allocate `thisBucketCount` number of `bucket` objects. So you need do:

```
 bucketP thisBucketArray = malloc(thisBucketCount * sizeof(struct bucket));

 if (thisBucketArray == 0) 
 { 
 /*handle error */
 }

 for (i = 0 ; i < thisBucketCount ; i++)
 {
    thisBucketArray[i].collisionCount = 0;
    thisBucketArray[i].firstKey = 0x00;
 }
```

Notice that I have removed the cast. [casting the result of `malloc()` is error-prone and dangerous.](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html)

You should also check if `malloc()` failed by checking if it returns `NULL`.

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes sense.  Could you please expand upon these two things that you've mentioned.  VLA's can't be initialized - It would seem to me that my array length is being hard coded, with `thisBucketCount`, how is it a variable length array?  Also, with typecasting malloc, why is that error prone?

Thank you very much for answering my question.

Comment: 1) It's not hard-coded. Your code is similar to this:`void func(intn) { int arr[n]; ...}` which declares a VLA. 2) The link should answer that question. `malloc` returns a `void*` which is compatible with any type object pointer. So no need to cast.

Comment: One more question, how would I make the type of `thisBucketArray` be a pointer, so I can return it by reference via the `createBucketArray()` function?

Comment: Already `thisBucketArray` is a pointer (you have typedef'ed with `struct bucket *`). You function returns a pointer as it is (including my suggested changes). Remeber `malloc()`ed memory lives throughout the execution of the program unless you free() it. You should `free()` that pointer once you are done.

Comment: Ok, I see that it does.  Why is it, if it is a pointer being passed by reference (as I want it to) that I can't use pointer notation, i.e. the `->` instead of `.` to access elements of struct array `thisBucketArray`?

Comment: Take for example,`struct somestruct *p = ...;`. `p` is a pointer to `struct somestruct` so you use `->` to access its members. But if `p` is a starting pointer of a set of elements then `p[0]` is *not* a pointer, It's a struct object (just like `struct somestruct val;`). So you can't use `->` notation on it and use `.`.